# Where are contracts used in the real world

Tags: contracts

I'd be interested to see some examples of [Bitcoin contracts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts) used right now.

- Websites that provide escrow services.
- Smart properties.
- Trading of contracts.
- Oracles.

Or are they not really in use right now?

Comment: There's a system of distributed oracles that launched last month - http://oracles.li/ , with a whitepaper available here: https://github.com/orisi/wiki/wiki/Orisi-White-Paper . Right now the test oracles allow for timelocking bitcoins, and there are other transaction / contract types coming soon, hopefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gregory Maxwell, Pieter Wuille, and theymos are using a 2-of-3 address to store a bounty for contributions to CoinJoin.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=279249.msg2983911#msg2983911

Update: A 2-of-3 escrow and arbitration site recently launched: https://www.bitrated.com/

Comment: https://bitgo.com/ is another one. I have an account with them but haven't transferred anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any that implement the advanced features in the protocol. But I do know of two sites that make it easier to do escrow transactions with 2 of 2 secrets:

www.bitescrow.org/

http://www.bit2factor.org/

There was also a bounty on the forums for an easy to use n of m escrow application that emailed all parties involved their secrets:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=294606.0